# Insert text at the bottom of beamer title page

Tags: beamer, titles

I want to insert some text (like collaboration information) at the bottom of the title page. I can insert the logo by using `\pgfdeclareimage`, I also want to insert some text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

You can redefine the `footline` template locally for the title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{T.H.E. Author}
\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vspace*{-1cm}\centering Some information\\ some more info\par} 
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
A     test frame without footline information
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: or simply, add some vertical space after `\titlepage` (and before, to compensate) and add the information:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{T.H.E. Author}
\title{Some Title}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}\titlepage  
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  \centering Some information \\ some more info\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
A test frame without footline information
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT2: to have the text appearing in every frame (as requested in a comment), you can redefine the `footline` template globally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{T.H.E. Author}
\title{Some Title}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \vspace*{-1cm}\centering\normalsize Some information\\[0.3em] some more info\\[0.3em]} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
A test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used second method. I have one image logo which I have inserted by \pgfdeclareimage and it appears in all pages. I have this text which I want to put as a logo. But it does not appear in all pages. Either I have to remove first logo from appearing in all pages or I have to make this text appear in all pages. Any suggestion how do to this.

Comment: @Manoj: I've updated my answer with a new example placing the text in every frame.